# In Clickhouse, how can I obtain the rows, in which all columns are non-null / not empty?

Tags: clickhouse

Consider the following table:

```
A    | B    | C
+++++++++++++++++++
15   |      | 25
10   | 20   | 30
```

which, for the sake of simplicity, contains only two rows. Now, when I issue this query

```sql
SELECT A, B, C FROM whatever
```

I would like to obtain only the second row, i. e. only these rows, where **every** value is non-null / not empty. Instead, I get both rows.

Is there a better way than doing the following? :

```sql
SELECT A, B, C FROM whatever
WHERE A != '' AND B != '' AND C !=''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function [empty](https://clickhouse.com/docs/ru/sql-reference/functions/string-functions/#empty) to mark empty or non-empty rows as 1 if the row is empty and 0 if there is any data in it.

So your code will look like this

```sql
SELECT A
      , B
      , C 
      , empty(A) as empty_A
      , empty(B) as empty_B
      , empty(A) as empty_C
FROM whatever
WHERE empty_A = 0 AND empty_B = 0 AND C empty_C = 0
```

Thus, if there is at least one empty in columns A / B / C, then these rows will not fall into selection

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer, just to be more straight, you can use the following code that combine the ***empty*** function with the ***trim*** one to spot also columns containing one or more white spaces.

```
SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3                            
  FROM my_table
 WHERE empty(trim(col_2)) = 0
```